# How can I commit only deletes with Git?

Tags: git

I know how to do:

```
git commit -a -m "whatever"
```

but I don't want to commit *everything*, just push up some files to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to add deleted files, try:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
git commit
```

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that he *already* `git rm`ed the files, but also made other changes that he doesn't want to commit.

Comment: +1, but it's slightly safer to do `git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm`

Comment: This would also commit changes to tracked files and already added

Comment: Ah i see - i misunderstood OP.. agree Mark i will update my example